# Going from string to double in java

Tags: java

I am trying to go from a double[] to a double, as I know the double array will only have 1 entry, and I need it to be a double for a class i wrote to work, i.e. I am trying to cheat a bit. My code is:

```
    double[] xHolder = new double[nodeHolder[a].length];
    double[] yHolder = new double[nodeHolder[a].length];
    for(int collector = 0; collector < nodeHolder[a].length; collector++){
        Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nodeHolder[a][collector].xValues)) = xHolder[collector];
        Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nodeHolder[a][collector].yValues)) = yHolder[collector];
    }
```

but when I use that I get: "variable expected"

Am I mistaken in the use of Double.parseDouble() and Arrays.toString()? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You've got your variables on the wrong side

Comment: Lord, I am sorry, I am tired, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an assignment, left hand side should be a variable which makes your below lines of code invalid:

```
Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nodeHolder[a][collector].xValues)) = xHolder[collector];
Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nodeHolder[a][collector].yValues)) = yHolder[collector];
```

Answer (score 0):

These statements are illegal(you will need to have variables on left side):

```
 Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nodeHolder[a][collector].xValues))
                            = xHolder[collector];
 Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(nodeHolder[a][collector].yValues)) 
                            = yHolder[collector];
```

The syntax for parseDouble is:

```
 Double d2 = Double.parseDouble("15");
```

`parseDouble()` takes String as argument.